# Python: Local variable reference before assignment

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to convert an XML file to Dictionary using Elementree. There are various tags in the XML file, but for every record, the ID tag is the primary key. So the dictionary I am trying to create has the parent tag as the ID and all other properties as its sub keys. But I am getting an unboundlocalerror saying that 'local variable x is reference before assignment. Here is the code:

```
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
temp_dict={}
def create_dict():
    test_dict = {}
    for child in root.iter():
        if subchild.tag=='ID':
                x=(child.text)
        else:
            test_dict[subchild.tag]= subchild.text
        temp_dict[x]=test_dict
    return ( temp_dict)
```

Comment: I guess I was able to figure out this one. Can you help me on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724345/python-unable-to-extract-attribute-using-xmltodict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work, you have to init `x` with a **root** Value or a `condition` and wait until the First `subchild` is found.
You have also assign `x =  test_dict` without `()`.

Example with Condition, for instance:

```
...
temp_dict={}
x = None
def create_dict():
    ...
        if subchild.tag=='ID':
            x = test_dict
    ...
        if x:
            temp_dict[x]=test_dict

...
```

Comment: Yeah..I got it! Thanks @stovfl