# OrderedDict: Unable Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmltodict

Accessing xmltodict converted values. I have an xml that looks like this

```
<PQ N="E90" RT="TG">
<CASES ASOF_DATE="8/11/2017" CREATE_DATE="8/13/2017" RECORDS="1130" >
<CASE>
<ID>E90</ID>
```

I am trying to access the CASE dictionary. If I remove the second XML line and try returning d[PQ]['CASE'], I get the desire result Here is the code for that:

```
def convert(xml_file, xml_attribs=True):
    with open(xml_file, "rb") as f:
        d = xmltodict.parse(f, xml_attribs=xml_attribs)
    return (d['FUND'])
```

This is how the output of d looks like:

```
OrderedDict([(PQ, OrderedDict([('@N', 'E90'), ('@RT', 'TG'), (CASES,   
OrderedDict([('@ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('@CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'),  

('@RECORDS', '1130'), (CASE, [OrderedDict([('ID, E90), ..... so on
```

Comment: `CASE`is inside `CASES`, therefore you need `d[PQ]['CASES']['CASE']

Comment: It doesn't go like that. Since it creates an ordered dictionary, it doesn't allow d[PQ]['CASES']['CASE']. I can share the output when I return d. That might be helpful

Comment: This is how it looks like. I need to access the CASE ordered dictionary only.

Comment: @stovfl. Can you please help?

Comment: return (d[PQ][CASES][CASE])
KeyError: CASES

Comment: @stovfl: OrderedDict([('@N', 'E90'), ('@RT', 'TG'), ('CASES', OrderedDict([('@ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('@CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'), ('@RECORDS', '1130'), ('CASE', [OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90'),

Comment: `'CASES'` is there, so you should be able to access. The only different from your Questions Output, THIS is with enclosing `''`! Next try: `print(d['PQ']['CASES'])`.

Comment: Gives me the same key error that I had mentioned above

Comment: Looks like a **BUG**, give your exact Python Version, I'm on **3.4.2** works OK. Last try `print(list(d['PQ'].values())[2])`

Comment: On the same version. I get the following error: parser.ParseFile(xml_input)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 1046, column 2

Comment: @stovfl I get this as output: OrderedDict([('@ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('@CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'), ('@RECORDS', '1130'), ('CASE', [OrderedDict([(ID, 'E90')

Comment: OK, this is the '<CASES>' Node, now access xy['CASE'] if it fail convert also to `list`.

Comment: @stovfl  (list(d['PQ'].values())[2])['CASE'] worked!! Thanks!

Comment: Another Approach worth to try: `d.get('PQ').get('CASES')`.

Comment: @stovfl: Thank you so much. Regarding the other question, could you take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720160/python-local-variable-reference-before-assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Unable Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError.
>   I am trying to access the CASE dictionary.

---

> **Data**:
>
> ```
> od['PQ'] = \
>     OrderedDict({'@N':"E90", '@RT':"TG", 'CASES':
>         OrderedDict({'ASOF_DATE':"8/11/2017", 'CREATE_DATE':"8/13/2017", 'RECORDS':"1130", 'CASE':
>             OrderedDict({'ID':'E90'})})})
> ```

```
print(od['PQ'])
>>> OrderedDict([('@N', 'E90'), ('@RT', 'TG'), ('CASES', OrderedDict([('ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'), ('RECORDS', '1130'), ('CASE', OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90')]))]))])

print(od['PQ']['CASES'])
>>> OrderedDict([('ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'), ('RECORDS', '1130'), ('CASE', OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90')]))])

print(od['PQ']['CASES']['CASE'])
>>> OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90')])

print(od.get('PQ').get('CASES').get('CASE'))
>>> OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90')])

print('list(od[\'PQ\'])[2] {}'.format(list(od['PQ'].values())[2]))
>>> list(od['PQ'])[2] OrderedDict([('ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'), ('RECORDS', '1130'), ('CASE', OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90')]))])

for kv in list(od['PQ'].values()):
    print('od[\'PQ\'].values {}'.format(kv))

>>> od['PQ'].values E90
>>> od['PQ'].values TG
>>> od['PQ'].values OrderedDict([('ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'), ('RECORDS', '1130'), ('CASE', OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90')]))])

for k,v in od.items():
    print('items(od) {}:{}'.format(k,v))

>>> items(od) PQ:OrderedDict([('@N', 'E90'), ('@RT', 'TG'), ('CASES', OrderedDict([('ASOF_DATE', '8/11/2017'), ('CREATE_DATE', '8/13/2017'), ('RECORDS', '1130'), ('CASE', OrderedDict([('ID', 'E90')]))]))])
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: Can you please help me with this?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745314/convert-python-dictionary-into-html-tables